# Combine $_GET and $_POST in PHP?

Tags: php, database, post, get

for some friends and family (different sites), I created a script that allows them to input data into the database. With

```
echo ("<a href=\"./pagina.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "\">" . $row['ID'] . "<br>");
```

, I 'send' the ID of the requested table to the URL.

In pagina.php, I have this code:

```
ID: <?php echo $_GET["ID"]; ?>
```

That works, of course, but now I want to use that ID to also display the data from the database, so not from the URL. These values are `" . $row['onderwerp'] . "` and `" . $row['tekst'] . "` 
(There may be more values to come, but I'm just a beginner, trying to get something to work).

I know this is possible, but I just can't get anything to work, as I have just started learning PHP.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What does this have to do with combining `$_GET` and `$_POST`?

Comment: Well, that was the best way I could think of describing my problem. Apparently, it was. ^_^

Comment: But your question and the accepted answer have *nothing* to do with `$_POST`. It's still very unclear how `$_POST` is in any way relevant. I begin to suspect `$_POST` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT onderwerp, tekst FROM yourtable WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "{$row['onderwerp']} - {$row['tekst']}<br />";
}
```

Comment: Kudos to @Mark B for reading your mind, then. There's not a single bit of $_POST in this answer, so I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: I am a newcomer here. In my PHP-page, I use both $_GET and $_POST. I want the ID in the URL to decide what ID (row) of the database is being displayed (and to my understanding, that is being called, $_GET), and $_POST to fill in the rest of the information. Yes, I mis-formulated my question, but I explained what I meant and luckily, there was someone who understood me. Seriously, stop beating newbs with this kind of comments...

Comment: @Aart: combining get/post in a single script is usually considered bad form. instead of doing `<form action="script.php?id=7">`, put the id=7 into a hidden form field, then you can refer to ONLY $_POST in the script.

Comment: *hereby answering another, unanswered question I was just having* You are awesome man! :D
Thanks, also for the explanation. However, I do need both the URL-information and the database reference - I bet I'm saying this wrong - , because there is no form in the page that information is being send from. Just links. I would give a link, but it is protected.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care whether data came from a `$_COOKIE`, `$_GET`, or `$_POST`, you can use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Don't use the Request superglobal, it's insecure and unreliable.

Comment: @NevStokes: It's neither of that. That myth originates in a cursorily understanding of the actual implications of a cookie fixation.

Comment: @Nev Stokes COOKIE, GET, and POST are all insecure and unreliable - they are client-provided data. As long as you're aware of this fact you can use them safely.