# How to send a part of the form with GET, another with POST?

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I'm echoing out a form that uses the method GET to send material via several input type="hidden". Like this:

```
echo '
<form action="somewhere.php" method="GET" name="whatever" id="whatever">
   <input type="hidden" name="get_method" value=" . '$foo' . ">
   <input type="hidden" name="want_to_send_with_post" value=" . '$my_post' . ">
</form>
';
```

This works fine, but how do I send one of these input types as POST, since it's the form that determines the method? Is there a way that an individual input type can override the form method? I know that an input button can override the form method (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formmethod.asp)), but that's creating a separate entity. I want to send both GET and Post simultaneously.

The reason: I want to send category names with Get and a text message with POST.

Comment: the better solution i see, is to send it by AJAX, put your get_method value in the url and post method value in params

Comment: Short answer, you have to either create a separate form or do 2 ajax requests. What possible reason could you have for doing that? Just send it all with POST.

Comment: I haven't yet learned AJAX. I wanted to send it with GET because I wanted to be able to bookmark it or navigate to different queries by changing the query. Thanks for your answers, I figured there was some other trick involving AJAX, but I first wanted to make sure that I hadn't missed out a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can! Specify the GET data in the URL you're heading to.

(I would edit the GET info with javascript as the user inputs their data)

```
<input type="text" id="get"> <!--user types get stuff here-->
<form action="somewhere.php?get=something" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="<?= $mypost ?>" />
</form>
```

Use JS to change the GET action

```
var form = doc.getId("form")
var get = doc.getId("get").onkeyup = updateLoc;

function updateLoc() {
    form.action = "somewhere.php?get=" + get.value;
}
```

Then PHP can deal with `$_POST["post"]` and `$_GET["get"]` separately.

Comment: +1 nice, I was not looking for a JS solution, but I might have a second look at it. Also, I read that it's not so recommendable to combine a Get query in a form that uses POST. I could be mistaken, though. Addendum: I read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809616/combine-get-and-post-in-php 

 Marc B wrote:

"combining get/post in a single script is usually considered bad form. instead of doing <form action="script.php?id=7">, put the id=7 into a hidden form field, then you can refer to ONLY $_POST in the script." –  Marc B

Comment: @DanSebastian I mean, I would personally look for a solution that uses just POST, but you asked for one that uses POST && GET, so there you go :P

Comment: True, it's the closest we get to a solution not involving AJAX.

Comment: @DanSebastian I know this is specifically what you asked for, but just in case, please also note that this will only work for forms where method="POST". If you ever need to use method="GET" you will lose everything in the query string in the action parameter.